# ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded spark-excel

Tags: excel, scala, csv, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have the following error when i try to read a 12mb xlsx file using spark-excel :

`ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded spark-excel`

I tried to use the property **maxRowsInMemory** to limit the number of rows loaded to memory, but still not working.

the code :

```
spark.read
  .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
  .schema(schema)
  .option("header","true")
  .option("maxRowsInMemory ", 3000)
  .option("dateFormat","dd-MM-YYYY")
  .load(in)
```

Comment: are you running in local or cluster ?

Comment: Depending on the size of each row and your spark configuration and setup, it is quite hard to give you a silver bullet, but you can try lowering the `maxRowsInMemory` to something like `20` as it is shown in the README (https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel).
If this doesn't solve the issue, then please open an issue on the repository, the team is trying to collect all OOM related issue to see if there is a common pattern behind it (see https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel/issues/142).